# Why do some drive have the expand menu option greyed out?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-explorer

I cannot open some drives by clicking on the drive. If I right click the expand option is greyed out.

I can access the drive only by typing the drive letter in the address bar.

For example, if I type D: then I can see inside drive D.

However, if I click the D drive, I can't see anything.

Here is a picture to illustrate:

[image: explorer screenshot]

Notice that drive D obviously has files. Yet there is a yellow button in Drive D while there is a black lock in drive H, for example.

Notice that all drive, D, E, H, F are set to automatically unlock and should have been unlocked by bitlocker.

In fact, this screenshot shows that we already can see content of drive D.

[image: explorer screenshot]

Comment: The symbol indicates the drive is protected by BitLocker.  Most of your screenshot is covered by the context menu.  The drive in question is currently locked which is likely the reason you cannot the contents of it (but again the vital information is actually illegible).

Comment: Please edit your question and include a picture of *File Explorer* with **"This PC"** selected.  This will show more clearly which volumes are encrypted by bitlocker and which are unlocked.

Comment: All volumes are unlocked and protected by bitlocker.

Answer (score 1):

The bold 'unlock drive' is why you can't access it - it's got some form of encryption applied and windows cannot natively show you the files inside it at this time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved. I was working with the other drives to change permissions. That's why I cannot expand. However, now the issue is solved. Once the other drives change permissions are completed all are marked open. Why not earlier, I have no idea.